# Need help parsing strings of the form "var1=bob&var2=smith" in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm new to C and need to parse the string "var1=bob&var2=j" that I am passing into a function as a char pointer. I would like to just return a char array such as ["bob","smith"].

I'm having a bit of trouble with the C syntax and have not been able to successfully loop over the input and extract out "bob" and "smith" in this case by parsing it. I have been trying to mess around with strtok() but unsuccessfully.

If anyone could help me out here it would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you have, a program which can call your function with a suitable sample string and a data structure which is suitable to store a result. The latter you can demonstrate by setting it to the desired values, i.e. skipping the parsing. If you can do that please show a [mre] of it. If you cannot do that then please first https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Generally please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Typically parsing strings is hard if you want a robust parser and handle errors. You really have to think of what rules the input must follow. Do you accept the following `"var1 = bob & var2 = smith"`? And what about `"var2=smith&var1=bob"`? What about errors, can you assume that the input string is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strtok won't work since the delimiter is changing (&var2=, &var3=).

The basic program to print out the names is simple.

```
int main() {
    char* str = "var1=bob&var2=smith";
    // iterate all characters
    for (int i = 0; i < str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        // if equal is found, you have your word
        if (str[i] == '=') {
            // keep iterating the characters upto & or \0
            for (int j = i+1; str[j] != '\0' && str[j] != '&'; j++) {
                printf("%c", str[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will need to create a **char*** array to store those names.

Answer (score 0):

I would treat this problem by first splitting the input string into tokens on the ampersand ("&"), then split each of the individual tokens on the equal sign ("=").
I mostly work in C#, where this would be trivial:

```
string[] tokens = ("var1=bob&var2=smith").Split('&');
foreach (string s in tokens)
{
   string[] parts = s.Split('=');
   Console.Write(parts[0] + " = " + parts[1]);
}
```